# Subcover of a compact Manifold

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a *compact* smooth manifold and $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i=1}^s$ a *finite* atlas for $M$.

> > I want to show that exists an open cover $(V_i)_{i=1}^s$ of $M$ such that for each $1\leq i\leq s$ I have $\overline{V_i}\subseteq U_i$.

Here is my argument.

For each $1\leq i\leq s$ and for each point $p\in U_i$ let $B_p$ be an open set containing $p$ such that $\overline{B_p}\subseteq U_i$. (Is is easy to show the existence of such $B_p$ by taking a smooth chart in a ngbhd of $p$). Now the set $\{B_p\mid p\in U_i \;\text{and}\; 1\leq i\leq s  \}$ is an open cover of $M$ and thus it contains a finite subcover $B_{p_1},\dots, B_{p_r}$.

For each $1\leq i\leq s$ put 
$$V_i=\bigcup_{j\; :\; \overline{B_{p_j}}\subseteq U_i}B_{p_j}$$ if the set $\{j\; :\; \overline{B_{p_j}}\subseteq U_i\}$ is not empty, otherwise put $V_i=B_p$ where $p$ is an arbitrary point of $U_i$.

**Question**: is my proof correct? Is there a smarter/shorter way to prove this? (Or this argument is fairly "well optimized"?)

Comment: Is it necessary that the initial atlas $(U_i, \phi_i)$ is finite? If it were a countable atlas you could make the same construction and get a countable collection of $(V_i)$. You still need the compactness of the manifold to construct the $V_i$ via the finite collection of balls though. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct and I do not see that there is shorter way to prove it. Perhaps you should explicitly mention that the closure of the union of finitely many sets agrees with the union of their closures.